# ¿Cómo mostrar consulta a la base de datos con php en la misma pagina donde se realiza la consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Sucede que estoy agregando unos formularios dentro de un modal a un sistema web en **PHP** que ya esta hecho, pero mi duda se encuentra en que tengo un `input text` y un `button submit`dentro de un `form` que aparece dentro del modal y yo quiero realizar una consulta a la base datos cuando se presiona el botón y mostrar los datos de la consulta justo debajo del `input text` y el `submit`.

No quiero que me muestre la consulta en otra pagina, lo que quiero es que se muestre debajo del `form` de búsqueda, si me pudieran orientar un poco de como podría lograr eso??

[image: imagen del form]

Esta es la consulta que realizo y que quiero mostrar debajo del formulario:

```
<?php  
$codigo = $_POST["Codigo"];  

$buscar = "SELECT id_cod,tipo_card,puntos,sucursal,fecha FROM tblcliente WHERE tblcliente.id_cod = '".$codigo."'";
$result=mysql_query($buscar); 
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
   echo "<table border = '1'> \n"; 
   echo "<tr><td>Codigo</td><td>Tipo</td><td>Puntos</td><td>Sucursal</td><td>Fecha</td></tr> \n"; 
   do { 
      echo "<tr><td>".$row["id_cod"]."</td><td>".$row["tipo_card"]."</td><td>".$row["puntos"]."</td><td>".$row["sucursal"]."</td><td>".$row["fecha"]."</td></tr> \n"; 
   } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
   echo "</table> \n"; 
} else { 
echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Puedes usar Ajax, necesitarás controlar el evento en el boton de submit, enviar una peticion $http recibir la información y mostrarla donde desees

Comment: agrega el formulario y la consulta que quieres hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como mencione en mi comentario, puedes usar Ajax

```
//controlar el submit del formulario
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    //evitar la accion de redirección del submit
    e.preventDefault();
    /* aqui tendrías que hacer la petición  y mostrar la respuesta */
    $.get( "ajax/consultar.php", function( data ) {
      $( ".resultado" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: trayendo los datos con ajax puedo mostrarlos en donde yo desee?? y podria tambien conservar los datos de la consulta en memoria para trabajar con ellos??

Comment: claro, en ese caso esta buscando alguna etiqueta con la clase llamada "resultado" para motrar la data.

Comment: tendrias algun ejemplo mas claro amigo?? es que me queda un poco ambiguo esto, de antemano muchas gracias por la info y el tiempo

Comment: si mira al momento de usar $(".resultado") , lo que hace es buscar una etiqueta ( por ejemplo un "div" un  "p", etc) , que tenga como clase "resultado"  osea (  <div class='resultado'>  ) si la encuentra entonces la respuesta que se encuentra en la variable data la colocará en ese "div" o "p", espero se me entienda.

Comment: oh si ya te entiendo amigo, muchas gracias.

Comment: y como puedo hacer uso de esos datos una vez que los obtengo con la consulta??

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza `jQuery.ajax()` y `json.org`.

Ajax, jQuery y PHP es una combinación de las que molan. Te permite, con relativamente poco esfuerzo, crear aplicaciones interactivas, dinámicas y atractivas. Y si añadimos JSON como formato de intercambio de datos la cosa aún se pone mejor. En este tutorial vamos a ver un pequeño ejemplo, explicado paso a paso, de todo esto junto y funcionando: jQuery, Ajax, PHP y JSON. Si queréis saltaros la explicación, podéis ir directamente al ejemplo.

> NOTA: Para continuar con el tutorial deberías tener conocimientos básicos de PHP y jQuery.

**¿Qué es Ajax y que es JSON?**

Ajax son las siglas de Asynchronous JavaScript And XML y es una tecnología que permite a una página web actualizarse de forma dinámica sin que tenga que recargarse completamente. JavaScript es el encargado de comunicarse con el servidor enviando y recibiendo datos desde la página web, en el servidor la solicitud es procesada y se envía una respuesta que es interpretada de nuevo por JavaScript en la página web.

Aunque con Ajax se puede solicitar cualquier tipo de recurso web, el intercambio de datos entre la página web y el servidor ha sido realizado tradicionalmente, como el propio nombre indica, en formato XML (eXtensible Markup Language), un lenguaje de marcas que permite definir una gramática específica y, por tanto, permite el intercambio de información estructurada y legible.

Y llegó JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), más ligero y con una notación más simple, y se convirtió en el formato más utilizado para el intercambio de datos cuándo se trabaja con Ajax. Además, con una ligera variación (JSONP) puede utilizarse en solicitudes Ajax entre diferentes dominios (cross-domain).

El formato JSON tiene la siguiente notación:

```
{key : value, key2 : value2, key3 : value3,...}
```

Y también puede ser serializado y multidimensional, por ejemplo:

```
[{key : value, key2 : value2, key3 : value3, key : { key : value, key2 : value2, key3 : value3} },{key : value, key2 : value2, key3 : value3,...}]
```

Puedes ver todas las especificaciones del formato JSON [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

**JSON en PHP**

En cualquier instalación estándar de PHP, desde la versión 5.2.0, se incorpora de forma predeterminada la extensión JSON y es muy fácil pasar los datos de un array a notación en JSON. Aunque si no se cuenta con esta extensión se puede construir la notación JSON de forma manual, es recomendable tenerla si vas a trabajar de forma frecuente con datos en formato JSON.

Entre las funciones de la extensión JSON para PHP que nos interesan, la más imprescindible es la función **json_encode()**. Con esta función podemos pasar nuestros datos a formado JSON rápida y fácilmente. Sólo es necesario tener los datos en forma de array u objeto. Por ejemplo:

```
$jsondata = array();

if( isset($_GET['param']) ) {

    if( $_GET['param'] == 'valor' ) {

        $jsondata['success'] = true;
        $jsondata['message'] = 'Hola! El valor recibido es correcto.';

    } else {

        $jsondata['success'] = false;
        $jsondata['message'] = 'Hola! El valor recibido no es correcto.';

    }

    //Aunque el content-type no sea un problema en la mayoría de casos, es recomendable especificarlo
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($jsondata);
    exit();

}
```

**Ajax con JSON y jQuery**

```
Uno de los argumentos del método jQuery.ajax() es dataType y aquí podemos especificar que vamos a utilizar datos JSON en la respuesta. Si no especificamos nada en dataType, jQuery intetará detectar de forma automática el formato de los datos recibidos. Si en la respuesta desde el servidor se especifica, como hicimos en el ejemplo anterior, el tipo de contenido, será más fácil para jQuery tratar los datos correctamente. Utilizando jQuery.ajax() tendría un aspecto similar a:
```

```
$.ajax({
    // En data puedes utilizar un objeto JSON, un array o un query string
    data: {"parametro1" : "valor1", "parametro2" : "valor2"},
    //Cambiar a type: POST si necesario
    type: "GET",
    // Formato de datos que se espera en la respuesta
    dataType: "json",
    // URL a la que se enviará la solicitud Ajax
    url: "script.php",
})
 .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
     }
 })
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
     }
});
```

Además del método anterior, podemos utilizar el atajo `getJSON()`, que quedaría de esta forma para hacer exactamente lo mismo:

```
$.getJSON( "script.php", { "parametro1" : "valor1", "parametro2" : "valor2" } )
    .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
            console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
        }
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
            console.log( "Algo ha fallado: " +  textStatus" );
        }
});
```

Ten en cuenta que .getJSON(), como su nombre indica, siempre hace una solicitud con el método GET, si necesitas enviar la solicitud mediante método POST tendrás que utilizar otras funciones de jQuery como .ajax() con el argumento type puesto a POST o su alias .post(). Por ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {"parametro1" : "valor1", "parametro2" : "valor2"},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "script.php",
})
 .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
     }
 })
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
     }
});

//Equivalente a lo anterior
$.post( "script.php", { "parametro1" : "valor1", "parametro2" : "valor2" }, null, "json" )
    .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
            console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
        }
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        if ( console && console.log ) {
            console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
        }
});
```

En el ejemplo PHP anterior, en el objeto JSON había dos miembros: success y message. Un posible objeto JSON recibido podría ser el siguiente:

```
{"success" : true, "message" : "Hola! El valor recibido es correcto."}
```

Este objeto es recibido en el método .done() a través del argumento data y podemos acceder al valor de cada miembro del objeto JSON del siguiente modo:

```
.done( function(data) {
    data.success;
    data.message;
});
```

**Acá un ejemplo paso a paso:**
`enlace`

Comment: y trayendo los datos con ajax puedo tambien mantener los valores en memoria por que requiero trabajar con algunos datos??

Comment: Puedes traer varios datos en la variable que retorna y tratarlos como tú quieras.

Comment: ok muchas gracias amigo, ya con tu ayuda ya me doy una idea, gracias, buen dia

Comment: @OlvertLeonides ¿ni un voto ni una aprobación de la respuesta? esta bien.

Comment: una disculpa amigo, apenas estoy aprendiendo a utilizar esta plataforma, pero en serio te agradezco tu tiempo y ayuda, gracias